# How to unite 2 arrays with objects without repetition in JS

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter

I have 2 objects.

```
const obj1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: 3}];
const obj2 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: 3}, {a: 7, b: 3}];
```

And I want to unite them in one but without repetitions.
the result should be obj3 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: 3}, {a: 7, b: 3}];

```
const obj3 = obj1.map((item) => obj2.filter((i) => i !== item));
```

is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you are mapping over an array, so basically you will do the `filter` every `obj1.length` time.

In term of the `filter`, filter will remove all the same item in `obj1` and you will only get the not duplicate item in `obj2`, you could group them.

Another good solution I would suggest is to `concat` the two array and `filter` it.

```js
const obj1 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: 3}];
const obj2 = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 8, b: 3}, {a: 7, b: 3}];
let obj3 = obj1.concat(obj2)

let obj4=obj3.filter((item,index) => obj3.indexOf(item) === index)
console.log(obj4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to loop through the first one and loop through the second one for each entry, checking for repetition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's handy to use the lodash library to handle array operations like the one you're asking about:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#union

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }];
var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

_.unionWith(objects, others, _.isEqual);
// => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }]
```

It's easy to add the lodash library to your code.  You can download and save the lodash.js file here: https://lodash.com/, or just use a url from a CDN and include with your other scripts/script tags: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js